Blowing Up along Reduced vs Non-Reduced Subschemes
In Eisenbud's book, 'The Geometry of Schemes' (see Proposition IV-40), he demonstrates a connection between blowing up schemes along reduced and non-reduced subschemes. Specifically, he illustrates that when blowing up $\mathbb{A}^2$ along the origin (reduced) and along the double point (non-reduced), the resulting schemes intersect after blowing up the nonsingular point in the former case and at the singular point in the latter.
How does the choice between blowing up along a non-reduced versus a reduced subscheme impact the resulting scheme's geometry and practical applications, and what insights does it provide into the intersection behavior of the blown-up schemes?
Eisenbud's explains, before the proof of the proposition, that the non-reduced case "preserves" more information: "the lines through the origin in the plane are not made disjoint" after the blow up. So  useful properties like the curvature are not effected (from what I understand at least).
Do you know any other similar examples or any useful facts/information about this that would help me understand it better ?

Vakil Exercise 22.4.H is an interesting example where blowing up the tacnode 2=4 by the subscheme (,2) in the affine plane lets you resolve the singularity in a single step, rather than requiring two successive blowups.
